# Consulta SQL con MAX( ) me trae 2 registros

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla que contiene nombre en SQL y código de un negocio, nombre y código de un item y cantidad de items vendidos. En la siguiente consulta los agrupe por negocio.

```
SELECT tabla1.* FROM 
#ItemXNegocio tabla1 
WHERE tabla1.ItemsVendidos = (SELECT MAX(ItemsVendidos) FROM #ItemXNegocio 
                        WHERE IdNegocio = tabla1.IdNegocio)
```

Da la casualidad que en uno de esos negocios hay dos items con la misma cantidad de ventas y me esta trayendo ambos pero yo solo quiero obtener uno, el que venga de primero por defecto.

Comment: Si es el primer registro en aparecer, pudiera servir `SELECT TOP 1 ...` (SQL Server), `... LIMIT 1` (MySQL, PostgreSQL), `... FETCH FIRST 1 ROW` (Oracle 12C+)

Comment: Por favor incluye la etiqueta del motor en el que trabajas. No vendría mal un pequeño ejemplo de los datos, o por lo menos la estructura de la tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mas recomendable es que si no necesitas todos los campos, solo proyectes los que quieras y agrupes

Por ejemplo

```
SELECT campo1, campo2,..., MAX(ItemsVendidos)
FROM #ItemXNegocio
GROUP BY campo1,campo2,....
```

Si en su defecto necesitas todos los campos, lo que podes hacer es un TOP 1 al principio del select (SELECT TOP 1...) (si estas trabajando en SQL SERVER) LIMIT 1 al final de la query (SELECT ..... LIMIT 1)

Si necesitas algun valor por defecto en particular, podes agregar una clausula ORDER BY al final. Supongamos que tenes 2 items con la misma cantidad de vendidos pero te interesa el primero que llego a ese numero, ademas supongamos que tenes una fecha de UltimoVendido o Update
Lo que podes hacer es

```
SELECT TOP 1 campo1,...., MAX(ItemsVendidos)
FROM #ItemsXNegocio
GROUP BY campo1, campo2,....
ORDER BY UltimoVendido DESC
```

o

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM 
   #ItemXNegocio tabla1 
WHERE 
   tabla1.ItemsVendidos = (SELECT MAX(ItemsVendidos) FROM #ItemXNegocio WHERE IdNegocio = tabla1.IdNegocio) 
ORDER BY UltimoVendido DESC
```

Espero te sirva!